# Steps to assign static IP address in CentOS Linux via command line?

Tags: linux, centos7, linux-networking

How to configure so the Linux CentOS v8 VM I have with static IP address?

I have already set the networking parameter during the GUI installation, but after the reboot, it still reverting back with DHCP IP addressing?

Do I have to create a new interface file rather than modifying the below:

```
 cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192
```

Note: I cannot even restart the network service as mentioned in the various blog:

```
[root@PRDSIEM01-VM etc]# systemctl restart network
Failed to restart network.service: Unit network.service not found.
```

Comment: The question is tagged as centos7, can you please confirm whether you mean 7 or 8?

Comment: Run this and send the output please: ifdown ens192 && ifup ens192; ip a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to configure the IP networking using the text user interface tool:

```
nmtui
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, networking on CentOS 7 and 8 is managed by NetworkManager.

It uses a plugin called ifcfg-rh to read the old network service configuration files (used in CentOS 6 and previous versions) such as the one you mentioned and translate them into the appropriate NetworkManager configuration.

What has probably happened here is that the interface name has changed from what it was during installation. This often happens with virtual machines running under VMware products. It looks like you had the interface name ens192 at install time. You can use `ip link` to see the current interface name.

If the name differs, you can edit the file and change the interface name within, then reload NetworkManager.

```
[root@PRDSIEM01-VM ~]# systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

---

While NetworkManager excels at managing networks for desktop/laptop systems, and certainly works for servers, it's quite heavy for that purpose. I've lately begun switching my CentOS 8 servers to the much lighter systemd-networkd, which is a bit better integrated into the system, but doesn't support desktop/laptop systems (particularly WiFi) as well. You might consider doing the same.

Comment: even after the restart and reload NetworkManager, the IP address is still not applied, despite the  cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192 shows updated static IP address.

Answer (score 1):

3

By default, networking on CentOS 7 and 8 is managed by NetworkManager.

It uses a plugin called ifcfg-rh to read the old network service configuration files (used [in](https://www.duplichecker.com/) CentOS 6 and previous versions) such as the one you mentioned and translate them into the appropriate NetworkManager configuration.

What has probably happened here is that the interface name has changed from what it was during installation. This often happens with virtual machines running under VMware products. It looks like you had the interface name ens192 at install time. You can use ip link to see the current interface name.

If the name differs, you can edit the file and change the interface name within, then reload NetworkManage